# erro ao tentar efetuar o login

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou fazendo um sistema de login e quando eu aperto no botão pra logar exibe esses dois erros aqui

> Warning: mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\200cono\vlogin.php on line 8
>
> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\200cono\vlogin.php on line 9

meu código do login e este aqui

```html
<?php 

include("admin/bd/config.php");

if (isset($_POST['Usuario']) && isset($_POST['Senha'])) {
    $Usuario = $_POST['Usuario'];
    $Senha = $_POST['Senha'];
    $get = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM nlogin WHERE Usuario = '$Usuario'");
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($get);

    if ($num == 1) {

        while ($percorrer = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get)) {

            if (password_verify ( $_POST['Senha'] , $percorrer['Senha'] )){

                $adm = $percorrer['adm'];
                $Usuario = $percorrer['Usuario'];
                session_start();
                if ($adm == 1) {
                    $_SESSION['adm'] = $Usuario;
                    header("Location: admin/index.php");
                }else{
                    $_SESSION['nor'] = $username;
                    header("Location: index.php");
                }

            }

        }

    }


}
```

Código da Config

```html
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$database = "site";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
// Create connection
$con = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
// Check connection
if (!$con) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: É erro na consulta, `mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM nlogin WHERE Usuario = '$Usuario'") or die(mysqli_error($con));` veja se aparece algum erro.

Comment: os erros persisti e agora apareceu esse Notice: Use of undefined constant con - assumed 'con' in C:\xampp\htdocs\200cono\vlogin.php on line 8

Comment: Acho q seria interessante colocar também o `config.php`

Comment: Pronto, adicionei

Comment: No seu arquivo config você está fechando a conexão no final  - mysqli_close($con). Retire essa linha e feche a conexão no final do arquivo login.

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo

Comment: @Bins, você não quer adicionar sua resposta para a questão ganhar o estado 'respondida'? E @ Wicaro aceitá-la como resposta?

Comment: @WesleyGonçalves, já adicionei a resposta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A conexão está sendo fechada dentro do arquivo "config", desta forma o arquivo de login não consegue executar a query. Remova a linha "mysqli_close($con);", seu arquivo config vai ficar da seguinte forma:

```html
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$database = "site";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
// Create connection
$con = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
// Check connection
if (!$con) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

No arquivo de login, encerre a conexão no final

```html
<?php 

include("admin/bd/config.php");

if (isset($_POST['Usuario']) && isset($_POST['Senha'])) {
    $Usuario = $_POST['Usuario'];
    $Senha = $_POST['Senha'];
    $get = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM nlogin WHERE Usuario = '$Usuario'");
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($get);

    if ($num == 1) {

        while ($percorrer = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get)) {

            if (password_verify ( $_POST['Senha'] , $percorrer['Senha'] )){

                $adm = $percorrer['adm'];
                $Usuario = $percorrer['Usuario'];
                session_start();
                if ($adm == 1) {
                    $_SESSION['adm'] = $Usuario;
                    header("Location: admin/index.php");
                }else{
                    $_SESSION['nor'] = $username;
                    header("Location: index.php");
                }

            }

        }

    }
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```